# Win7 problem with VB6 ocx registration

Tags: windows-7, vb6

Have a lot of older VB6 apps running at work and starting to bring in Win7 machine.

I run one and find an error of OCX registration along the lines of ...ocx is not registered.

```
RegSvr32 \\Uhsfp1\UserPrograms\sharedcomponents\UHSLineItems.ocx
```

and no errors when run as an admin from cmd prompt.

I run the app again and I read an error:

> An error was encountered granting
>   access to certain features in this
>   application.   ActiveX component can't
>   create object.

Really don't want users to see that.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a 64-bit machine? Try registering with `C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\regsvr32.exe` instead of the default which would be `C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe`. The former is the 32-bit version which should make your components available to other 32-bit programs.

Comment: No 32 bit, we don't waste money on hardware or MSDN licenses either.  ;->

Comment: Do the machines have UAC enabled? Are you registering the components as the administrator on the Win7 machines?

Comment: Yes was running cmd as an Admin.

Comment: Found that it was another hidden dll for our own error handling.  

JOY.


TIA

Answer (score 2):

Try unregistering the OCX and then registering it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the command prompt (or calling process) is [running elevated](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/) in order for regsvr32 to succeed on Windows 7